# textbox value to disable a checkbox based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I'm actually familiar with how to disable a textbox or checkbox but what im looking here is that a textbox of age that is automatically calculated based on DOB. See below code :

```
Private Sub TextDOB_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If IsDate(Me.TextDOB.value) Then
Me.TextAge.value _
= Age(CDate(Me.TextDOB.value), Date)
Else
Me.TextAge.value = "Invalid entry"
End If
End Sub
```

the results of the above code is such "27 yrs 9 months"
Now further on basis of this i have to disable a check box for pension only if the employee age is greater than 58.

Can i use the left function which we have in excel in a userform? tried something but didnt work out well. Please help

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: on TextAge_exit i tried to use a left function with in if condition  - if left(textage.text,2) >=58 then CheckPEN.value = False it gave me run time or compile error i guess. Can't share the code of what i tried initially as have deleted it

Comment: Never mind its working fine now. I was running the code on TextAge_Error instead of exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub TextAge_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If Left(Me.TextAge.value, 2) >= 58 Then
    Me.CheckPEN.value = False
    CheckPEN.Enabled = False
Else:
    CheckPEN.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```